# Can anonymous modules and class be nested in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, anonymous-class, class-hierarchy

I can define an anonymous class within an anonymous module:

```
c = nil
m = Module.new do
  c = Class.new
end

m #=> #<Module:0x007fad3a055660>
c #=> #<Class:0x007fad3a0555e8>
```

Is the above equivalent to:

```
m = Module.new
c = Class.new
```

In other words: does the concept of "nesting" actually apply to anonymous modules?

Comment: Define "defined under"

Comment: Interesting, anonymous modules are not registered in `Module.nesting`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've rephrased my question, maybe there is no nesting at all.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev “registered in `Module.nesting`” is an oxymoron :) `Module.nesting` method is a pure stack rewind on parsing stage: `while (cref && CREF_NEXT(cref)) ...`.

Comment: @Stefan No name ⇒ no luck. The closest attempt would be: `classes.each { |c| class << c; puts Module.nesting.inspect; end }`

Comment: Also, there is no “concept” _of nesting_. It is basically _a concept of **naming**_ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about being anonymous. Assigning a dynamically created class to a constant makes it named:

```
Foo = Class.new # => Foo
foo = Class.new # => #<Class:0x007fe5dd45d650>
```

Yet it still doesn't nest further:

```
module Bar
  Baz = Module.new do
    p Module.nesting # => [Bar]
  end
end
```

Or even about being dynamic for that matter:

```
module Quz
  eval 'module Qux; p Module.nesting; end' # => [Quz::Qux, Quz]
end
```

It's about scope gates.

---

As far as constants are concerned, there are only two scope gates - the keywords `class` and `module`.

Nesting is done purely syntactically. That is why you get the weird:

```
module Do
  X = 42
end

module Do
  module Re
    p Module.nesting # => [Do::Re, Do]
    p X              # => 42
  end
end

module Do::Mi
  p Module.nesting # => [Do::Mi]
  p X # => uninitialized constant
end

Do.module_eval   { p X } # => uninitialized constant
Do.instance_eval { p X } # => uninitialized constant
```

---

So if Ruby sees the keywords `class` or `module`, it nests the *"current node"* further. When the closing `end` is found, it goes up the tree. When a new constant is being defined, it places it in the current node.

Comment: So `Module.nesting` is just a stack of modules used for constant lookup. Every `module` (or `class`) keyword pushes an arbitrary module onto the stack (popping it at `end`). And the top-most element functions as a prefix for new constants.

Comment: Furthermore only _constants_ are stored and form an implicit hierarchy. The current nesting is transient and not stored anywhere – I can re-open the same module under different nestings. I would conclude: modules and classes cannot be nested, only constants can. Is that correct?

Comment: @Stefan, yes. Named classes/modules get stored in the current nesting because they are constants (start with capital letter).