# How many ways to include or inherit module inside a class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to understand concepts of including or inheriting a module inside a class. Whenever I read i get new ways to include or inherit a module inside a class. So just want to know how many ways are there. Here are the examples I am sharing:

**Example 1**

```
module TimeExtensions
  refine Fixnum do
    def minutes; self * 60; end
  end
end

class MyApp
  using TimeExtensions

  def initialize
    p 2.minutes
  end
end
```

**Example 2**

```
VAL = 'Global'

module Foo
  VAL = 'Foo Local'

  class Bar
    def value1
      VAL
    end
  end
end

class Foo::Bar
  def value2
    VAL
  end
end
```

**Example 3**

```
module Foo
  def foo
    puts 'heyyyyoooo!'
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

Comment: The three examples do very different things. You could instead ask what is the difference between the three. On the other hand, if you just want different syntaxes for the same, you can get quite a lot, but what is the point?

Comment: I was learning how to include a module inside a class .Every time I am seeing I am getting a different way .So my question is why there are 3 ways made to do one small thing..

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend is another possibility.

Comment: Those three things have exactly zero to do with each other. Also, what does this have to do with Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the three, only the last one includes a module into the class. That is, it adds the methods from the module to the class.

---

The first one is called refinement. If instead of refining `Fixnum` you just added a `#minutes` method to it, `Fixnum` will have that method for everyone that uses it, as long as your code is loaded. This might cause conflicts with other implementations of the same method (for example active record's `#minutes`) and leads to obscure, hard to debug issues. Instead, you can refine the `Fixnum` class and it will have that method only in the scope where you added the refinement with `using`.

It has some issues and it's not very widely used. But for the purposes of this question, the differences between including a module and using a refinement are:

- including will add methods to the class where you do the inclusion, while refinements make other classes behave differently in the context where they are used
- including is semantical (all objects will have the new included methods), while refinements are lexical (after you close the class, if you reopen it again, you won't see the refined methods)

---

The second one is scoping the class inside the module. This doesn't add methods anywhere. It is just due to the way constants are searched that if the constant (in this case `VAL`) isn't found in the current class, it is searched further up the tree. It's not that simple actually, if you want more details, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893577/2423164).